# Does a redis key is permenent if no expire value is set

Tags: redis

I'm setting up new redis server in my personal project.

If I do not set any timeout value using EXPIRE command the ttl is -1

I just want to know does -1 means permenent or default expire timeout.

If setting a key value sets ttl -1 then what is the purpose of PERSIST command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just want to know does -1 means permenent or default expire timeout.

Yes, if no timeout is set, the default TTL is `-1`, and the key won't be expired. However, it might be evicted when you run out of memory, check the `maxmemory-policy` configuration in *redis.conf*.

> If setting a key value sets ttl -1 then what is the purpose of PERSIST command

You CANNOT manually set a key's TTL as `-1` with `EXPIRE` command. If you do that, i.e. `expire key -1`, Redis will delete the key.

As you mentioned in your answer, `PERSIST` is used to remove the expiration setting, and make the key persistent.

Comment: I just want to make clear. Does keys set as persist also removed when it runs out of memory?

Comment: @Raghav As I mentioned in the answer, it depends on your `maxmemory-policy` configuration. Check [redis.conf](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L568) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.After little bit of research I found, key will expire only after given with EXPIRE command
Persist used to remove expire value if already given expire value for a key